# codeigniter realtime form validation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I wanting to validate my forms via ajax (jquery library).  Basically I have a form, that takes a password, this needs to be a minimum of 6 letters longs.

Currently I have the validation rule set as this,

`$this->form_validation->set_rule('password', 'passswprd', 'required|min_length[6]|trim')`

This works fine when submitted using traditional submition through PHP and POST.

However is there a way I can run my validation each time the users changes that field they are focused on?

Answer (score 0):

$(".field_id").live("blur", function(){ ajax call goes here });

You might want to just do the password validation with javascript though, since it shouldn't require serverside work. I'd do a final test with php, but generating traffic for a simple length check seems less than optimal.